# Node.js readline: Unexpected token =>

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline, console.readline

I am learning node.js and need to use `readline` for a project. I have the following code directly from the [readline module example](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html).

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log('Thank you for your valuable feedback:', answer);

  rl.close();
});
```

But when I run the code via 
`node try.js` command, it keeps giving out the errors like below:

```
rl.question('What is your favorite food?', (answer) => {
                                                    ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: What version of node you're using? Possibly the one that doesn't support ES6 arrow syntax.

Comment: @CherryDT Just did. Sorry, new to the community

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), one of the new features of the [ECMAScript 6 standard](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/), were introduced to node.js (as stable feature) only in [version 4.0.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/).

You can either upgrade your node.js version or use the old syntax, which would look like this:

```
rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', function(answer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log('Thank you for your valuable feedback:', answer);

  rl.close();
});
```

(Note that there is one more difference between those syntaxes: The `this` variable behaves differently. It doesn't matter for this example, but it may in others.)

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote. I am on windows and the version number is 0.12.2, which seems really old compared to 4.0.0. But I can't seem to upgrade it through npm (I am on Windows and used the command "npm install -g n"). Why is that?

Comment: I also had troubles upgrading using npm itself in older versions, I'm not sure what caused it, but I then just downloaded the [latest version from the node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and installed it. (And in the meantime, I switched to using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), a nice package manager for Windows, where it's a matter of typing `cup nodejs.install` to upgrade node.)

Comment: I just installed it through choco. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your node version.

Arrow functions now work in node (version 4.0.0) see here: [ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/)

Check to see which version you are running with `node -v`

You likely need to upgrade check out the compatibility table here to see what else is available:

[Node Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Answer (score 1):

For people who already upgraded node and are running into the same error: For me, this error was coming from eslint. I was using *node 14* in my `package.json`:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
```

But only got rid of the error after updating the linter `.eslintrc.js` config to the following:

```
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true,
    },
    "sourceType": "module",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `=>` syntax, known as an Arrow Function, is a relatively new feature of JavaScript. You'll need a similarly new version of Node to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your "es" version from 6 to 7.
For this go to your functions**>**.eslintrc.js file.

Change `"es6:true" to "es7:true"`.

[image]

Actually, "=>" is an element of es7 and therefore throws error on es6.